# Splitting a string and posting to cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell that contains a string that is spilt by commas (,).

I want to open the cell, and spilt the string and the place the string rows in column F starting at Row 10.

Trouble is nothing I do seems to be working and in fact now I am getting an error message saying it can't save.

Can someone help me please.

```
function splitString() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote List');
  var rowCount = 10;
  var copyViewQuote = ss.getSheetByName('View Quote');
  var theSplitString = ssSheet.getRange("L4").getValue();
  
  var spiltstring = theSplitString.split(",");

  for (var = i=1;i < 3; i= i+1){

  copyViewQuote.getRange("F"+ rowCount).setValue(spiltstring);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***FINDINGS:***

Your for loop structure `for (var = i=1;i < 3; i= i+1)` is incorrect, thus you get an error message saying it can't save. It should be like `for (i = 1; i < 3; i++)`,

***SOLUTION:***

You can try this tweaked script:

```
function splitString() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote List');
  var copyViewQuote = ss.getSheetByName('View Quote');
  var theSplitString = ssSheet.getRange("L4").getValue();
  var spiltstring = theSplitString.split(",");
  var data = 0;

  for(row=10; row<=10+spiltstring.length; row++){
    //each spiltstring array data is put on Column 6 or column F that starts from row 10 to 10 + length of the splitstring array
    copyViewQuote.getRange(row,6).setValue(spiltstring[data]); 
    data++;
  }

}
```

***SAMPLE RESULT:***

> Sample **Quote List** sheet w/ sample data on cell `L4`

[image]

> Sample result on **View Quote** sheet that starts on F10 and beyond (based on length of split text array from cell `L4` on **Quote List** sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues with your code that I reworked and included comments. I [created a file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boE02iwOGqk79Qz76x6AWwmyoY7HI9xCgWWMy4IOTLQ/edit#gid=0) that successfully does what I think you are trying to do. Copy and create your own version. I used the below code:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function splitString() {
  const listRow = 10; //Row 10
  const listCol = 6; //COlumnn 5
  const addressToPull = "L4";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quote List');
  const copyViewQuote = ss.getSheetByName('View Quote');
  
  var theSplitString = ssSheet.getRange(addressToPull).getValue();

  //Get the cell value as array, but single dimension
  var theWords = theSplitString.split(",");

  //Array that will hold values at 2-dim level
  var wordsTwoDim = [];
  for(var i=0;i<theWords.length;i++){
    //populates second array with extray layor of arrays()
    var singleWord = theWords[i];
      wordsTwoDim.push([singleWord]);
    }
  copyViewQuote.getRange(listRow,listCol,wordsTwoDim.length,1).setValues(wordsTwoDim);
}
```